# Selecionar últimas datas de cada mês SQL

Tags: sql, query

Gostaria de realizar um SQL para obter de uma lista de datas o último dia de cada mês.

---

Exemplo:
De uma lista de 01/01/2016 até 31/12/2016 retornar os últimos dias de cada mês: 31/01/2016, 28/02/2016... 31/12/2016.

A base de dados é no FileMaker.

Comment: Não sei se existe mas tipo se você ordenar sua pesquisa não adiantaria? Tipo 'order by id desc'

Comment: qual base de dados ?

Comment: `Order by id desc` só vai ordenar de forma decrescente, ele quer mostrar só os últimos dias de cada mês.

Comment: Você consegue usar consultas `SQL` manualmente no` FileMaker? Por exemplo `SELECT * FROM CONTATOS` OU só Script??

Comment: consigo executar consultar sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No filemaker não consegui nenhuma solução generica via SQL, o jeito foi gerar várias consultas para o periodo utilizando a Cláusulas OFFSET e FETCH FIRST

Answer (score 2):

Em `PostgreSQL` você pode usar assim:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(data, 'YYYY-MM-01')::DATE + 
       (INTERVAL'1 MONTH' - INTERVAL'1 DAY') AS data
FROM tabela
GROUP BY data
```

De uma olhada [nessa documentação](http://pgdocptbr.sourceforge.net/pg80/functions-datetime.html).

Answer (score 2):

O SQL Server 2012 pra frente você pode usar o seguinte:

```
SELECT EOMONTH(Data) from Datas
```

Em outras versões do SQL Server você pode fazer algo assim:

```
select DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,Data)+1,0)) from Datas
```

Em Oracle:

```
select LAST_DAY(Data) from Datas
```

Comment: Quando iniciei a resposta ainda não tinhas especificado a base de dados, mas vou mante-la pra caso outra pessoa precise.

Answer (score 2):

Outra forma de realizar essa consulta, somente com cálculos:

```
SELECT 
   DATEADD(month, ((YEAR(data) - 1900) * 12) + MONTH(data), -1) 
FROM
   Datas
```

Veja funcionando:
[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ed44a/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

No FileMaker, a função [date(month;day;year)](http://www.filemaker.com/help/12/fmp/html/func_ref1.31.18.html), ao constar 0 no parâmetro `day`, retorna o último dia do mês anterior. Por exemplo, `date(2;0;2016)` retorna o último dia de janeiro de 2016.

O uso combinado das funções [date()](http://www.filemaker.com/help/12/fmp/html/func_ref1.31.18.html), [year()](http://www.filemaker.com/help/12/fmp/html/func_ref1.31.29.html) e [month()](http://www.filemaker.com/help/12/fmp/html/func_ref1.31.24.html) permite obter o último dia do mês de data da tabela. Supondo que o nome da coluna seja DataVenda, podemos ter algo semelhante a `date((month(DataVenda) +1); 0; year(DataVenda))`

Comment: Então no `FileMaker` só pode ser usado script ?

Comment: via sql não dá?